# Is there any alternative to HTMLPane in SmartGWT with setContentsType as PAGE which is internally using iframe?

Tags: smartgwt

Is there any alternative to HTMLPane in SmartGWT, as the HTMLPane is internally using iframe when the setContentsType is as page

Sample code would be

```
HTMLPane myPane = new HTMLPane();
myPane.setContentUrl("/myapplicationContext/index.html");
myPane.setContentsType(ContentsType.PAGE);
addMember(myPane);
```

Comment: myPane.setContentsType(ContentsType.FRAGMENT); is showing blank page, any suggestions, basically Im trying to integrate / plugin one GWT application in another GWT application.